# Function throws an error if not run from inside a $timeout

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in my controller

```
$scope.initMap = function() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8
    };      
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}

$timeout(function(){$scope.initMap();}, 1); //This works
//$scope.initMap(); //Doing it like this causes the crash
```

Using the $timeout line the map is initialized fine, but using the bottom line Angular throws an error `a is null`, from somewhere inside the minified library.

I'm including the Google Maps js file just above my controller in the HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey& sensor=false"></script>
<div class="row" ng-controller="VenuesCtrl">
```

I assume it's something to do with the $timeout function rather than needed to wait for 1 millisecond, but I can't figure it out. Do I need the $timeout or can I make my code work without it?

Comment: Sounds like it happens because Google tries to use `id` DOM element  before  `map-canvas` element is rendered. I would create directive and call Google Map constructor from there

Comment: But would the 1 millisecond timeout make it render in time? It seems strange that such a small amount of time would make it work fine.

Comment: At $timeout 0 it still works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because Google tries to use id DOM element before  map-canvas element is rendered. I would create directive and call Google Map constructor from there

I think even with `$timeout` `0` it works too.

The function wrapped by `$timeout` executes after every other piece of code following the call to $timeout is executed.

> Why it works?

With timeout you just level down execution priority. Its a trick  to tell the browser to run it ASAP when other stuff done and browser is not busy.

---

You can google enough examples and demos how to write Google Map constructor with directive. I  use my own.

Here is a relevant code:

**HTML**

```
 <map-directive id="map_canvas" >                    
 </map-directive>
```

**directive**

```
app.directive('mapDirective', ['$log', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            /* ... */
        },
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


        var map = false;

       //...    


       initialize(document.getElementById(attrs.id));

     function initialize(map_id) {
        log.i("initialize Google maps");     


        var mapZoomLevel  = locStorage.get('mapZoomLevel', 12);
        var mapLast_lat =   locStorage.get('mapLast_lat', 34.060122481016855);
        var mapLast_longt = locStorage.get('mapLast_longt', -118.26350324225484);

        var options = {                                
            zoom: mapZoomLevel,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapLast_lat, mapLast_longt),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            panControl: false,
            scrollwheel: true,
            draggable: true,
            rotateControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: false
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), options);
       //...
      }
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll give the directive a try. Is it possible to pass the directive a attr like `map-var="map"`, and in my controller $scope.map would be the map it renders?